# Laptop keyboard spamming

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I spilled a little water on it yesterday, worked fine after I cleaned it but today one button keeps spamming either `*` or `\` (it shouldn't be wet).

Any tips?

Other buttons don't work when those are being spammed.

---

after a few hours it's still not working, i took the keyboard out dryed it still nothing.
can it be saved or do i have to buy a new one?

Comment: Depending on the laptop. Take it apart and see if any water is in between you would be surprised how even a little spill will leave just a bit of water inside the keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laptop Keyboard Water Damage](http://superuser.com/questions/558338/laptop-keyboard-water-damage)

Comment: Completely drying everything can take a very long time if water has seeped into nooks & crannies or between layers (days).  It may help to do as much disassembly as you're comfortable with and then set a hair drier at a low temperature setting and have it blow on it for at least several hours.  Another trick is, after the disassembly and removal of as much moisture as you can get at, put it in a sealed plastic bag with a lot of desiccant packets, then leave it for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard is shorting, most likely because water is acting as a conductor somewhere. Put your laptop out in the sun for a couple/few hours with the lid open (and just forget about it you'll be okay without it) to get the air and heat in to evaporate the water. That should take care of it.